# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Case-insensitive properties were deprecated in 3.3 and support will be removed two minor releases later

Tags: matplotlib

Warning : PS C:\python-workspace\Inheritance> py -3 .\Denoising.py
.\Denoising.py:18: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Case-insensitive properties were deprecated in 3.3 and support will be removed two minor releases later  plt.plot(t, f, color = 'c', LineWidth = 1.5, label = 'Noisy')

Problem Description :
I am trying to add two sinusoidal signals and noise. Tried to plot the signals but observing the mentioned warning. Below are the other required details.

Python Version : 3.7.3
IDE used : Visual Studio Code
Date : 08-12-2020

SCRIPT:

```
# Plotting a Signal and its Noise version 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 12]
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':10})
                     
#Create sample signal with two frequencies               
dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(0, 1, dt)                     
f = np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*120*t)    # Sum of two frequenciesK
f_clean = f

f = f + 2.5*np.random.randn(len(t))                   # Add Noise
                     
plt.plot(t, f, color = 'c', LineWidth = 1.5, label = 'Noisy')                     
plt.plot(t, f_clean, color = 'k', LineWidth = 2, Label = 'Clean')                     
plt.xlim(t[0], t[-1])                     
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Replace `LineWidth` with `linewidth` and `Label` with `label`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove capital letters from `LineWidth`. Changing them to just `linewidth` instead will solve the problem.